# PHP multiple tables data pagination

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a database there are 2 tables - 10 records in each of them;
I want to retrieve all the data, so there will be 20 records in a response;
On each page should be only 5 records listed, so there will be 4 pages at the bottom to switch between;

When I retrieve data from database I must query each table in a separate query.
And there is a problem, because when I set limits and offset afted choosing a page number 4 there won't be records to retrieve from each tables, and each query will give me no data, because limit is 5 and offset is 15 then, but in each tables there is only 10 records;

Is it possible to solve such a problem? I'm not searching for implementation, only for text explanation;

I don't use any framework, just simple `mysqli_query` during db connection (it's a very old project)

Thanks for advices!

Comment: It is pretty much totally unclear what your problem is.  Sample data and desired results would really help.  And, it seems quite unreasonable to issue a separate query to each table.

Comment: I must query each table, it is a very bad architecture there. Why do you need sample data, it's a theoretical question, it doesn't matter what data it is exactly. It could be one column `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible with UNION but that problem represent very bad database architecture and you should change it (merge into one table) before bigger problems comes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UNION` and split each table query into it's own query?

Example:

```
([query_from_first_table]) UNION ([query_from_second_table]) LIMIT 5;
```